# Select Insert and Update in One Query MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert, sql-update

I am trying to update one table from 3 tables which is working fine, but i want to update a table from 3 after i insert data in 4th table, here what i am doing

```
INSERT INTO relation_table(cid,pid,liid,lnid,lgid,l_key)
SELECT  a.cid,
        a.pid,
                b.liid,
                c.lnid,
                d.lgid,
                md5(CONCAT(a.cid, a.pid, a.lurl, c.lnid, d.lang))
FROM    links a
        INNER JOIN links_table b
            ON a.lurl = b.lurl
        INNER JOIN lname_table c
            ON a.lname = c.lname
                INNER JOIN lang_table d
            ON a.lang = d.lang
where a.checked != "3" limit 2;

update links SET checked='3'
WHERE lid=a.lid
```

Last statement is not working for update

Please help ;)

Comment: `a.lid` is unknown in the second statement. And it's a bad idea to use `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel thx for pointing ORDER BY .... Yaa a.lid is unknown how can i fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE links a
INNER JOIN links_table b ON a.lurl = b.lurl
INNER JOIN lname_table c ON a.lname = c.lname
INNER JOIN lang_table d ON a.lang = d.lang
SET a.checked='3'
WHERE a.checked != '3' LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Thx for reply .... i am bit confuse ... so what will be the full query ... if i am deleting my update and use yours its giving error ... can you please show full query if u dont mind ;)

Comment: Its not working giving error ;( .... [Err] 1221 - Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT